# In AHK cancel button is still running the application

Tags: autohotkey

```
full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if (!(A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)")))
{
    try
    {
        if (A_IsCompiled)
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}

Gui, Add, Button, x10 w80, OK ;
Gui, Add, Button, xp+380 yp w80, Cancel ;

Insert::
Gui, Show,, %varTitle% ;
Pause, On ; Pause the Script Here and Wait for User Input

ButtonOK:
Run notepad
Pause, Off
;GuiEscape: ; Note: single colon here, not double
Gui, Cancel
Pause, Off
return
Pause, Off
return

F12::
send {F12}
sleep, 3000
Process, Close, notepad
Pause, Off
return
Pause, Off

ButtonCancel:

Gui, Cancel
return
Pause, Off
return
```

When using Cancel Button AutoHotkey (AHK) still launches the application. How to resolve this? Although the OK button functions properly but cancel button still launches the application

Comment: [pause](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Pause.htm) just waits for _any_ input, I think you need to use [inputbox](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/InputBox.htm) or [input](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Input.htm)